# Is it possible to use Open Type Fonts (.otf) in SQL Reporting Services (2008)

Tags: reporting-services, fonts

When you try to select a font of type .otf that has been installed on Client & Server then the font does not appear in the dropdown list of available fonts.

The font can be used fine in word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a response back from MS. Apparently otf fonts aren't supported in .net and hence not SSRS.
So basically no!